Data Mismatch Error When trying to make a range = to a long formula
I am trying to insert this formula into a dynamic range, and I cannot get the last formula to enter as I keep getting a Data Mismatch error message. I think this is because I am getting lost in the quotation marks for all of the interior functions. Any advice on how to get this formula to post into the cells? the final formula in the cells should be as follows:
=IF(H4=0, "0-Current" , IF(H4>$L$1,"0") & "++" , TEXT(K4,"0") & "-" & TEXT(J4,"0")))


Dim lastrowI As Range, lastrowJ As Range, lastrowK As Range

Set lastrowI = Range("H300").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
Set lastrowJ = Range("H300").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)
Set lastrowK = Range("H300").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3)

Range("I4", lastrowI).Value = "=MIN(ROUNDUP(G4/$I$1,0)*$I$1,$K$1)"
Range("J4", lastrowJ).Value = "=I4-$I$1+1"
Range("k4", lastrowK).Value = "=IF(G4=0,""0-Current"",IF(G4>$K$1,TEXT($K$1,0)" & "" + " ,TEXT(J4,0)" & "" - "" & "TEXT(I4,0)))"


Can you show us what the final formula should look like in the cell? Not sure but you may want: ‘=IF(G4=0,””0-Current””,IF(G4>4K$1, TEXT($K$1,0) & “” + “”, TEXT(J4,0) & “” - “” & TEXT(I4,0)))”

@cybernetic.nomad the final formula in the cells should be as follows: =IF(H4=0, "0-Current" , IF(H4>$L$1,"0") & "++" , TEXT(K4,"0") & "-" & TEXT(J4,"0")))

@cybernetic.nomad that worked, thank you! all the quotations are quite confusing at first
